# Cloudfront caching algorithms

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Does CloudFront keep all objects in cache, all the time, until they were invalidated.

I had assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that they would be using some sort of LFU/LRU based caching algorithm to deal with infrastructure costs

Can anyone let me know if Cloudfront uses LFU algorithm to maintain objects in cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have been notified that they use a LRU algo for invalidating "unpopular" objects in cache. Found this out the hard way since all of our content was getting invalidated after 24 hours even though the cache control was set to 1 year.